# Can we pass custom URL for 'Send' option, in Docusign embedded sending

Tags: docusignapi

We want to integrate Docusign e-signature in our web-application. We want to use embed sending and signing both features in our application. Below is the scenario:

1> User logs on our application. Selects a document which he wants to get signed from some user.

2> We create an envelope in draft mode(by calling REST API) and then calls EmbeddedSending flow so that sender can review/make other changes in the document.

3> once all review is done by sender, on clicking 'Send', we want to send emails to the recipient/s, which will point to an url redirecting them to our application where EmbeddedSigning flow will start.

Can we achieve this functionality using both embedded flows(EmbeddedSending/Signing) together or do we need to call different REST APIS separately to work it this way?
Any help/pointers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can definitely use the embedded sending and signing flows on the same envelope.  It sounds like you're on the right track, you'll basically do something like this:

1. [Login API](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Authentication/Authentication/login/) to retrieve the user's `baseUrl` and other data.
2. [Embedded Sending](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createSender/) (aka Sender View) API to open the sending view of an envelope where the user can add tabs, documents, recipients, etc.  NOTE: Make sure you set the `clientUserId` for any recipient who will sign using embedded signing (you'll need to use that same value in step 3).
3. [Emdedded Signing](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient/) (aka Recipient View) API to open the signing view of that same envelope in step 2.

There's also a page on [Embedding](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign#Embedding) in the DocuSign Dev Center.

Comment: Thanks Ergin,it helped alot. Here is what I did for redirecting recipients to our application, once they get email from docusign and click link: Signer signer = new Signer();
  signer.setName(recipientName); 
  signer.setEmail(recipientEmail);
  signer.setClientUserId("1111");  signer.setEmbeddedRecipientStartURL("https://ourOwnAppLink.com");